# How to remove a special characters from the parsed string

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I am parsing a price of some items from a website. However, I am getting some irrelevant special characters before the string. How do I remove those characters and the string that I want?

I am getting

```
\n                \n                    \n                    \n                \n\n                \n                    \n                    \n                        AMD YD2600BBAFBOX 3.9GHz Socket AM4 Processor
```

and                     `&nbsp;&nbsp; 17,975.00`

However, I have used Replace method to replaced the unwanted special characters from the string

```
itemName = itemNameNode.InnerText.Replace("\n", "");
itemPrice = itemPriceNode.InnerText.Replace("                    &nbsp;&nbsp;", "Current price:");
```

Still I am not getting the expected result. I am getting the result as

[I have linked my image here for reference. It doesn't allow me to post image here (Seriously! stackoverflow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWrBE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a replace on the newlines for your `itemName` string, you could simply use [String.Trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2). Trim removes any leading or trailing characters on the string that return true to a `char.IsWhiteSpace` call, of which a new line character is included.

```
var x = "\n   Hello   \n";

Console.WriteLine("-");
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine("-");
/* Output:
-

   Hello   

-
*/

Console.WriteLine("-");
Console.WriteLine(x.Trim());
Console.WriteLine("-");
/* Output:
-
Hello
-
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd try it like this.

```
itemName = itemNameNode.InnerText.Trim();
itemPrice = itemPriceNode.InnerText.Trim().Replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;", "Current price:");
```

How about using `Trim()` before using `Replace()`

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Yes, I have used the 'current price' to compensate with the `&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Now I replaced my code as `itemPrice = itemPriceNode.InnerText.Trim().Replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;", "").Trim();`

Thanks for your suggestion.